# Error while installing easysnmp through pip [Python]

Tags: python, pip, snmp, easysnmp

A complete beginner here.

I've been trying to install the easysnmp library for python, and I've been encountering all sorts of cryptic c compiler related errors, I've solved most of them, but I've encountered an error that I've got no clue how to solve: (sorry for the gigantic error message)

```
Collecting easysnmp
  Using cached easysnmp-0.2.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: easysnmp
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for easysnmp ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\PC\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-fozy8z\\easysnmp\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\PC\appdata\local\temp\tmpieeeempip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\easy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\session.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\variables.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  copying easysnmp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
  running build_ext
  building 'easysnmp.interface' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\easysnmp
  C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\include -IC:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\PC /Tceasysnmp/interface.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\easysnmp/interface.obj -Wno-unused-function
  cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-function'
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for easysnmp
  Running setup.py clean for easysnmp
Failed to build easysnmp
Installing collected packages: easysnmp
  Running setup.py install for easysnmp ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\PC\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-fozy8z\\easysnmp\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\PC\appdata\local\temp\pip-lsjd2u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\easy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\session.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\variables.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    copying easysnmp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\easysnmp
    running build_ext
    building 'easysnmp.interface' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\easysnmp
    C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\include -IC:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\PC /Tceasysnmp/interface.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\easysnmp/interface.obj -Wno-unused-function
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-function'
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\PC\Miniconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\PC\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-fozy8z\\easysnmp\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\PC\appdata\local\temp\pip-lsjd2u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\PC\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-fozy8z\easysnmp
```

Im not entirely sure if the error is c compiler related or something to do with the library itself, or maybe something in between, and I could really use some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7?

Comment: @lord63.j yep, installed it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at this time, the `Easysnmp` package is *not* Windows-compatible. This has been confirmed in [issue #32](https://github.com/fgimian/easysnmp/issues/32), which has been closed Feb 28, 2016.