# python easysnmp packge install error windows.. failed with exit status 2

Tags: windows, python-3.x, networking, snmp, easysnmp

I need to use snmp to get some information from my devices (port statistics, port description etc..) 
but I'm struggling with some package install error that I didn't find any answers 
I'm using windows 10 64bit machine and trying to install `easysnmp` package,
but I'm getting the following output:

```
> D:\Python36\Scripts>pip.exe install easysnmp
Collecting easysnmp
Using cached easysnmp-0.2.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: easysnmp
Running setup.py install for easysnmp ... error
Complete output from command d:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import 
setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AVISHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-
build-9_9zhm70\\easysnmp\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
 C:\Users\AVISHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wia8b3wa-record\install-
 record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
'net-snmp-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\easy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\session.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\variables.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
copying easysnmp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\easysnmp
running build_ext
building 'easysnmp.interface' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\easysnmp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Id:\python36\include -Id:\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tceasysnmp/interface.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\easysnmp/interface.obj -Wno-unused-function
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-function'
*****error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2***** 

Command "d:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AVISHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9_9zhm70\\easysnmp\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AVISHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wia8b3wa-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AVISHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9_9zhm70\easysnmp\

*****error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2*****
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773652/error-while-installing-easysnmp-through-pip-python

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't answer completely because I've only ever used EasySNMP on Linux machines, but Python's EasySNMP module makes use of [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html) underneath; I daresay you'll need to download and install that first (that's what I've had to do to use it on Linux).

Best of luck!

EDIT: A reply to your post cites a duplicate question which refers [an issue on the EasySNMP Github](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/easysnmp/issues/32) explaining that Windows isn't supported by EasySNMP- sorry buddy! You could give PySNMP a try, I think that's pure-Python (so theoretically platform independent).

Answer (score 0):

I successfully built and installed EasySNMP 0.2.5 under Windows 10, 64-bit.
I took a simple script form EasySNMP page, but got mixed results.
The script doesn't work from command line. It says:

```
C:\Python\eLearning>python easytest3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "easytest3.py", line 2, in <module>
    session = Session(hostname='10.1.7.130', community='public', version=2)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\easysnmp-0.2.5-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\easysnmp\session.py", 
line 280, in __init__ self.sess_ptr = interface.session(
    easysnmp.exceptions.EasySNMPConnectionError: couldn't create SNMP handle
```

Although it works perfectly from IDLE 64-bit, which came with Python. So far I have no idea if it's an issue with libraries, settings, etc :(

Just in case,

> Python 3.8.3, 64-bit Net-NSMP 5.7.1

Comment: How did you manage to install it? I am having the same problem as OP and can't seem to get around this error unfortunately.